# Probability of a dice game: win, lose or draw.

Tags: probability, fair-division

$C$ and $J$ play a game. $C$ always starts. $C$ rolls a fair dice first and wins if he throws an even number. If not, then $J$ rolls the dice. If she rolls an odd number she wins. if neither win it's a draw. a) What is the probability of the game being drawn? b) Is this game fair?  If they played the game $100$ times how many games should $J$ win?

Comment: What have you tried?  Note that these rolls are just like flipping a coin, as even and odd each have probablity $1/2$  There are only three possible outcomes, so write them all down and assess the probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the game was fair then the probability that $J$ wins should be $1/2$, since that is the probability that $C$ wins. But a draw is possible. This can also help you figure out the last part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a) The probability of a draw is simply that C rolls an odd number and J rolls an even number, i.e. it is $0.5\cdot0.5=0.25$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for existing. Next thank you for answering my question but what's the logic? My assumption was that a win & a lose would be 3/6. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Well, you have two players here and each of them rolls the dice independently. C has a probability of winning of 50 percent (3/6). The same applies to J, but he only plays after C, so only when C loses first.